# ClickOnce through TFS & Release Management

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, clickonce, release-management, ms-release-management

I have seen quite a few blogs around managing a ClickOnce application through TFS up to Visual Studio 2010. The process seems a little convoluted and so I cannot help but wonder if there has been any improvement with later versions of VS? I am using 2015 (VS, TFS & RM) so would love to hear of anyone has had more luck doing this on later versions.

Any help on the matter would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

These settings worked for me :

```
/target:publish /p:PublishDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"/ /property:ApplicationVersion=1.0.0.$(Build.SourceVersion)
```

The `$(Build.SourceVersion)` variable will be the changeset / git commit id.

[image]

[image]

Then you can create a release to deploy this somewhere.

- Create a website to deploy to.
- Click `Artifacts` to select the artifact to deploy.
- Select `IIS Deployment` to choose machines in a deployment group.
- Click the menu icon highlighted to select the drop folder.
- For further documentation about certificates + signing see other clickonce docs.

I think there's another option to create an html page, but you can just link to the `.application` file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new build system vNext Build to achieve it. Just need to add *Publish Build Artifacts* step in the build process. You could write a PowerShell script, if you want to copy ClickOnce output to some directory like UNC path/IIS website folder. Here is a blog with detailed steps: [Building ClickOnce apps using build vNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/tfssetup/building-clickonce-apps-using-build-vnext)

If you still insist on using XAML build, [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2015/09/15/build-and-publish-a-clickonce-app-using-team-build-vso.aspx) will also meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the Patrick! I had come across the XAML page already and it all makes sense, but I am having trouble with my working Directories not cooperating as I expect for copying out the Published files... I was hoping to stick with XAML as I have been using Agent based Release Management for other related projects so didnt want to buck the trend with this one if I didnt have to. I am curious to know if you have had any luck with these tutorials yourself??